# Ruby, bundle, SSH and Jenkins

Tags: ruby, shell, ssh, jenkins, bundler

I have a Jenkins job that uses `Publish Over SSH Plugin` to send `script.sh` to a remote machine and execute it. The script looks like that:

```
cd some_path
bundle
bundle exec rakep build
```

I get the following error

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
```

The same script runs correctly if I SSH to the machine and run it manually or do

```
echo "bash script.sh" | ssh me@remote_machine
```

After some research I found that this error on a local machine can be fixed by using a login shell or (re)installing bundle. I did the latter with no effect. The former may be the direction, but the Jenkins plugin does not allow me to configure anything which sounds like it.

I thought that the cause of error might that the plugin SSHs in such a way (non-login shell?) that some environmental variables are not set - so I added `export VAR=value` for any `VAR` I found in `env` while manually SHHed that had anything to do with Ruby. Still no effect.

I am not familiar with Ruby and hope that it is not a silly problem. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Using `which ruby` I found out that Jenkins was indeed using another Ruby executable than me, even though we used the same SSH credentials.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple ruby versions installed on the system, and the user you're trying to log in as is configured to use a different one than the system ruby.  If Ruby is installed to somewhere in /home, that could be the cause of your issues.  See if you can control the way that Jenkins is running the script, or which credentials it is using the get into the box.

Comment: Jenkins uses the same user that I do.

Comment: You can probably narrow down the problem by logging in and running `which ruby`, then comparing to a Jenkins ssh'd script that runs `which ruby > /tmp/whichruby.txt` and looking at that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, unfortunately they did not work.

I solved it using

```
~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.1 do bash script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line on top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
```

If you are using rvm (which I believe you do), rvm is changing current version of ruby every time you enter the folder containing Gemfile. This bit of functionality is stored in `~/.bash_profile` which needs to be loaded - this is done by adding `--login` option.

Comment: That did not work, probably the Jenkins plugin calls `bash foo.sh` explicitly and this first line is not processed.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved a similar problem configuring the slave as follow:

[image]

Comment: I must be using a different plugin - in don't have that field in this form.

Comment: @kikicarbonell: You sir, just saved my ass!! It works great for me!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using rvm or rbenv? They're probably not loaded in the non-interactive ssh session.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the reason was that the **PATH** variable was different when logging in from a console or when running a script via SSH.

You can take a look at how **PATH** differs and add the missing paths to the script that you are running

```
export PATH=$PATH:/missing/path/here
```